# How to modify an existing back up database task

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to modify and existing sql server 2005 maintenance plan.  It's currently set to run a full backup that will expire in 3 days.  It is also set to append existing under if files exists.  I want to set it to overwrite if files exist however that particular dropdown is greyed out.  I have full rights to the system and to SQL server.  How can I get it to let me choose overwrite?  In creating a new job the very second I tell it to create a backup file for every database it greys out the option on if files exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can come to duplicating your situation shows that when I select All Databases it switches the target backup file from **Back up databases across one or more files** over to **Create a backup file for every database**, at which point the **If backup files exist** options becomes irrelevant because SQL Agent will create unique filenames for the backup files.  Check to see if that's the case for you.  If so you'll have to reset it back over to backup across one or more files and choose your file again.

Comment: That's exactly what the issue was.  No wi have to figure out how to get 1 file per backup per DB